# How to set variable from select statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a `SELECT`  statement that returns 3 values, and I want get the data in those values. Can you help me please?

My code is :

```
declare @id int
declare @selected_name varchar(50)
declare @selected_age int
declare @selected_salary money

Select 
    name, age, salary 
from 
    people 
where 
    id = @id 

set @selected_name = name 
set @selected_age = age 
set @selected_salary = salary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
select @selected_name = name, @selected_age = age, @selected_salary = salary 
from people 
where id = @id;
```

Make sue this will need to have a single/unique entry, if that is not the case then you need `top` clause :

```
select top (1) @selected_name = name, @selected_age = age, @selected_salary = salary 
from people 
where id = @id;
```

Comment: thank you for your help